# Timestamp to NSDate strange result

Tags: ios, sdk

I have made a unix timestamp converter to NSDate and time for native check.
I always get the date and time 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 or 01-01-1970 01:00 returned.
I have checked the timestamp with online converters and its good. 
timestamp example: 1381350121

Whats my problem?

Code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[responseData objectForKey:@"expire"] intValue]];

NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *ExpireSession =[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", date, ExpireSession);
```

Also tried this:

```
NSString * timeStampString = [responseData objectForKey:@"expire"];
NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *ExpireSession =[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", date, ExpireSession);
```

Comment: It would help if you show all intermediate results.

Comment: timeStampString = 1381350121

Comment: NSDate *date = 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: NSString *ExpireSession = 01-01-1970 01:00

Comment: What is the value of `_interval`?

Comment: 0.000000 is the value in double %f

Comment: Then `timeStampString` must contain some (perhaps invisible) characters that break the conversion to double. Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [timeStampString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])` to see the raw bytes?